# Error : Fatal error: Call to a member function escape_string() on a non-object

Tags: php, sql

I am getting the error:

"Fatal error: Call to a member function escape_string() on a non-object" It says this error appears on line 214 of my code. Below you can see that code.

```
 // Check description, more than 0 characters
    if (isset($_POST['description'])) {
        if (strlen($_POST['description']) > 0) {
            $description = $conn->escape_string($_POST['description']);
        } else {
            $errors .= "desc|";
        }
    } else {
        $errors .= "desc|";
    }
```

The line of code below is the specific offending code according to the error message

```
$description = $conn->escape_string($_POST['description']);
```

Any idea what may be causing this error?

Thanks

Comment: for quick diagnostic, do a `var_dump($conn);` The error is telling you that it is not an object

Comment: So what is `$conn`? How is it set?

Comment: ensure the page that contains the offending code has a DB connection. Are you including the `$conn` via an `include`? Assuming `escape_string` is a custom function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you're either looking for [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or [add_slashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) or [html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php), depending on what you want to achieve next.